# PdfBox: Sign PDF with just signature generated on mobile client [Without Private Key and Certificate]

Tags: pdfbox

We are storing Public Key, Private Key and CA Ceritificate on the client. There is no way we can pass it to the server for signing. We are creating a signature on the client and want to send it to the server for signature embedding. The purpose is to keep the client as light as possible also the same server code we can use for all clients. So is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox supports external signature container creation. For usage details cf. the `pdfbox-example` classes `CreateSignatureBase`, `CreateSignature`, `CreateVisibleSignature`, and `CreateVisibleSignature`. In particular check the comments of the `isExternalSigning` and `isLateExternalSigning` property definitions and usages.

Thus, the server can

- can prepare the PDF for signing,
- extract the bytes-to-sign, and
- forward them or their hash to the client.

Then the client can

- sign the given data and
- push the resulting signature container to the server.

Eventually the server can

- inject this signature container into the previously prepared PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This approach looks fine. I can implement it but do you know any other easy approach. Maybe using the different library? Because I have to implement two-way communication between client and server to implement this and don't have enough time.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I'm usually only working with secure signature creation devices on the server side.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. @mkl Is there any way to extract bytes to sign on the client?

Comment: and is the bytes to sign will be same for a pdf file in multiple iterations?

Comment: *"Is there any way to extract bytes to sign on the client?"* - yes, simply look at the example classes referred to above. *"and is the bytes to sign will be same for a pdf file in multiple iterations?"* - probably. But it shouldn't, creation/modification time stamps and the pdf id should differ.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, @mkl.